# Should the meta site be in Esperanto?

Tags: discussion

We have discussed the language of the main site and decided on a mix of Esperanto and English, but we never considered the language of the meta site, should that be in exclusively in Esperanto? At the moment it is in English, which seems odd; although many users have English, Esperanto is the language all users are likely to have in common.

Ni diskutis la lingvo de la ĉefa ejo kaj ni decidis uzi miksaĵon de esperanta kaj la angla, sed ni neniam konsideris la lingvon de la meta ejo. Ĉu ĝi devus esti ekskluzive en Esperanto? Nuntempe estas en la angla. Tio ŝajnas stranga; kvankam multaj uzantoj scipovas paroli la anglann, esperanto estas la lingvo ĉiuj uzantoj verŝajne havas komune.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the help, oversight, and guidance of the Stack Exchange Community Team, and the support of the developer staff who fields your feature requests, bug reports, and system support issues… **your meta posts should be in English.**

Comment: Nu, vi povus *lerni* Esperanton... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Please no. As an outside observer (who doesn't speak Esperanto), I'm somewhat interested in the site and language... but if all your guidance is in Esperanto, I don't have a chance at participating.

I'd definitely favor *allowing*, and even encouraging the use of the language on meta, but by no means should English and other languages be disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

Mi proponas ke ĉiu skribu en la lingvo en kiu tiu preferas skribi. Tio estas (laŭ mi) la plej bona metodo por havi maksimuman partoprenadon.

Kiel multaj Esperantistoj, la Angla ne estas mia denaska lingvo, kaj mi ege preferas uzi Esperanton. Mi bezonas almenaŭ trioble da tempo por skribi mesaĝon en la Angla ol en Esperanto (mi mezuris).

Legi mesaĝon facilas kompare al skribi mesaĝon, do se okazas ke iu tute ne komprenas Esperanton, tiu povas uzi tradukilon (Google Translate sufiĉe bonas en Esperanto->Angla) aŭ peti tradukon al la komunumo per komento. Mi ne vidas problemon se en la sama paĝo estas mesaĝoj en malsamaj lingvoj.